# Test-Connection and Variable

Tags: powershell, variables, null, invoke-command

```
$server = "SOME_SERVER"
$target = "8.8.8.8"
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock { Test-Connection -ComputerName $target }
```

So I have this code and it's throwing me an error

> Cannot validate argument on parameter 'ComputerName'. The argument is
>   null or empty. Supply an argument that is not null or empty and then
>   try the command again.

Strange thing is that if I change `$target` to `8.8.8.8` in last line, everything's fine.

Can someone explain this to me, please? I've been struggling with this for like an hour and searched internet looking for an answer but didn't find any solution. Is this some kind of a bug in PowerShell?

BTW - if I invoke `$target`, it's giving me `8.8.8.8` and the type is String, so...

Answer (score 5):

Your local variables are not available in a remote connection.

You need to either pass it as an argument:

```
... -ArgumentList $target -ScriptBlock { param($target) ...
```

or utilize the [`$using` scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-5.1#the-using-scope-modifier):

```
... Test-Connection -ComputerName $using:target ...
```

Answer (score 2):

`Invoke-Command` does not pass your local variables to the target system. `$server` does not have `$target` defined, thus the `Test-Connection` command will fail since `$target -eq $null`, as the error states. To fix this, you can pass the remote server an argument, using the `-ArgumentList` parameter. For example:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock { Test-Connection -ComputerName $args[0] } -ArgumentList $target
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a structured approach:

```
$source = 'myserver'
$destination = '8.8.8.8'

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $source -Credential (Get-Credential) -ScriptBlock {
    param(
        [Parameter()]
        [string]$destination
    )    
    Test-Connection $destination
} -ArgumentList $destination
```

The `-Credential` parameter is useful if the current user lacks the required privileges.